# Convert excel data to txt file in html format

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to combine details from excel column1 & column2  to get a text file as shown in figure, excel can have upto 100 rows. Here is the picture of excel data which is limited to 3 rows for the time being :
[image]
Here is the txt format on which I want my output:
[image]
I have developed the code but since I am not a regular vba programmer so couldnt be able to hit the target.
Here is output I am currently having after suggested edits: 
[image]

Here is my code:

```
 Dim c As Range, r As Range
    Dim output As String
    Dim txt1 As String
    Dim txt2 As String
    Dim txt3 As String
    Dim txt4 As String
    txt1 = "<div class=" & Chr(34) & "promo_img col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" & Chr(34) & ">"
    txt2 = "<!-- PROMOTIONAL IMAGE -->"
    txt3 = "</div>"



    For Each r In Sheet1.Range("A1:C3").Rows
        For Each c In r.Cells
            output = output & "," & c.Value   ' & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & txt2 & Chr(10) & Chr(13) &
        Next c
        output = txt1 & vbNewLine & output & vbNewLine
    Next r
    Open "D:\DOCS\text.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, output
    Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use code below:

```vb
Dim c As Range
Dim output As String
Dim txt1 As String
Dim txt2 As String
Dim txt3 As String
Dim txt4 As String
txt1 = "<div class=" & Chr(34) & "promo_img col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" & Chr(34) & ">"
txt2 = "<!-- PROMOTIONAL IMAGE -->"
txt3 = "</div>"

output = ""
For Each c In Sheet1.Range("A1:A3")
    output = output & txt1 & vbnewline & vbnewline & txt2 & vbnewline 
    output = output & "<a href=""" & c.value & """ target=""blank"">"
    output = output & "<img src=""" & c.offset(,1).value & """/></a>"
    output = output & vbnewline & vbnewline & txt3 & vbnewline & vbnewline
Next c

Open "D:\DOCS\text.txt" For Output As #1
Print #1, output
Close #1
```

`vbnewline` will change to a newline
`""` will return a `"`

Comment: dear spacing issue is there as it not appearing just like the one required for html

Comment: @UmarFarooq what spaceing issue?

Comment: dear I have added file after running you code please see if you can make it to the original one...There are spacing and gaps which need to be there to run html

Comment: Thanks dear, it is almost there some I have updated the output, you see in required version first line has around 10 chars left indentation  & other two have 15 chars & then again last one has 10 chars indentation from right border, if you can sort that too...thanks

Comment: @UmarFarooq you should try add as many `vbtab` or `" "` as you want  as indentation.